# Is there any way to import data to a colab notebook from another colab notebook without using drive?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is there any way to import data to a colab notebook from another colab notebook without using drive? Or can I get the previous runtime type data if I change the runtime to gpu without using drive?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the data on your PC and then upload it to the other notebook.

Comment: Thank you for reply @Fran Arenas, I know this procedure. But the size of the data file is approximately 16 gb.  Whenever I'm trying to download the data, after some time it's showing download failed. I tried to mount with google drive, but google drive only have 15 gb. so is there any other way?

Comment: @Shibaditya99 Which is the format of your data? You can compress or partitionate it. For example, if it is a csv you can compress it to parquet format or you can split it in 3 csv

Comment: It's actually KITTI dataset

Comment: @Shibaditya99 So, split the csv in multiple small ones and import them.

Comment: KITTI datasets are not CSV. There are 3 types of format i.e .bin, .png, .txt and 4 datasets like lidar, image, label & calibration. I tried to make a zip,  but the zip is approximately 15gb